# Calling Script through a proxy from frontend to CDN

Tags: sitecore-client, cdn, ssc

We are trying to implement "`Partytown`" to serve third-party scripts through ***webworker*** service where for ***metarouter*** the Script URL needs to come from CDN to which Sitecore has access but the frontend system is not having access. thus we are creating a proxy, frontend will give Sitecore a URL to access, and Sitecore should access that URL and return whatever it is there (the get request)

If I try to do a hit on the service from Sitecore I get the result while hitting it through the frontend system via the backend gives a 403.

I tried using [**ServicesController**] from `Sitecore.Services.Core` but did not resolve the issue. Trying it through `CORS` but any leads on this are welcome.

> ERROR SAYS : Strict origin when ross origin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was happening because of Firewall, we created a WAF rule allowing certain request URIs and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Your Problem statement, in summary is the proxy service created when hit from the backend gives an error with status code 403 (forbidden)

you are trying to solve it using `CORS`, that is the correct approach.

you will have to add your proxy service DNS under "`AllowedOrigin`"

please check the detailed explanation here:
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors-.html

hope this helps.