# CORS Issue on Partytown access in SItecore Application

Tags: sitecore-client

What does the below error mean and how can we resolve it?

```
Access to fetch at 'http://cdn/..' from origin 'https://xyz.com' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response 
serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the 
resource with CORS disabled.
```

The parties involved here are partytown and Sitecore application

Comment: Is it the one you asked before? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/33431/calling-script-through-a-proxy-from-frontend-to-cdn

Comment: Yes @SumitBhatia, solution was same to the problem , i have updated the answer in the attached question. Thanks